# Roboguice 2.0 injecting application into POJO

Tags: android, dependency-injection, roboguice

I'm newbe in Roboguice, please help. I have an application calss `MyApplication` in which in `onCreate` method i initialize some data. Also i have a `POJO` with buisiness logic which i want to use in my `MainActivity` (See code snippets below). I need to inject `MyApplication` into `POJO` to get access to data which i initialize in application's `onCreate`, but this code called before `onCreate` and i've got a `NullPointerException`.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private Properties applicationProperties;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        applicationProperties = loadApplicationProperties(APPLICATION_PROPERTIES_ASSET);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public String getProperty(String key) {
        return applicationProperties.getProperty(key);
    }

}

@Singleton
public class POJO {

    @Inject
    private MyApplication application;

    @Inject
    public void init() {
        // NPE here, because application onCreate not called at this moment
        serverURL = application.getProperty(Constants.SERVER_URL);
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends RoboActivity {

    @Inject
    private POJO myPOJO;

}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve it eventually?

Comment: Not yet, I'm just make my app a singleton and obtain instance in POJO via MyApplication.getInstance() without injecting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Found a way to do this in RoboGuice 2.0 based on the answer in [RoboGuice custom module application context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15638981/2291).

Inject the application context in AbstractModule constructor, then bind it in `configure()` for later injection:

```
public final class MyModule extends AbstractModule
{
    private final MyApplication context;

    @Inject
    public MyModule(final Context context)
    {
        super();
        this.context = (MyApplication)context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(MyApplication.class).toInstance(context);
    }
```

}

Comment: There is a bug https://code.google.com/p/roboguice/issues/detail?id=193&thanks=193&ts=1335334124 in RoboGuice 2.0 that in some cases may need you to bind to a provider that simply wraps the context instance. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/roboguice/XYZdGm_2fNg/riyiDLWHlpcJ for example workaround code.

Answer (score 1):

If the data you need doesn't require a context, just access to XML resources or res/raw, you can inject that from anywhere.

Just use `Roboguice.getInjector()` to obtain a copy of the Resources object.