# RoboGuice custom module application context

Tags: android, dependency-injection, roboguice

How do I get the application context in my custom module? Here is the code for my module:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void configure() {
        // Package Info
        try {
            final PackageInfo info = application.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    application.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            bind(PackageInfo.class).toInstance(info);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the metadata for the application. The default module version of PackageInfo doesn't have meta data, hence I need custom binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just inject it in constructor

```
public final class MyModule extends AbstractModule
{
    private final Context   context;

    @Inject
    public MyModule(final Context context)
    {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void configure() {
        // Package Info
        try {
            final PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            bind(PackageInfo.class).toInstance(info);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work .. I suspect i was missing something obvious. Do you know of a full example of using a custom module with RoboGuice 2.0? The default example with RoboGuice doesn't use custom module.

Comment: @Mubix This part is from a working app. What does it mean, didn't work? In case a context was null or invalid, I would try to inject _ContextProvider_ instead context.